# Where to put @Transactional and the logic which invokes two or more tables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently developing a web server using Spring Boot. 
Since I am a beginner in Spring Boot and server and I have no developer around me,
I am not sure if I am doing all right or all wrong.

My project structure on Spring Boot server is like this.

[image: Spring boot structure]

As you see there are six entities, which are tables in MySQL.

Each of them has its controller, service and repository. (and the repositories implements JpaRepository)

Clover is a lottery name like Powerball.

If a user buys a clover, that clover should be added to a purchased clover list which is CloverValid in the picture, and user's point has to be decreased by 10.

So, when a user clicks a button on a website or an android app, 
the server has to update the user's point in User table,
and insert a value of new clover - his id and a timestamp.

And of course those two operations should be transactional.

I want to know where to put this logic.

I think it's service so should I add a new service class or 
change the whole structure?

If I do have to change this structure and start again
please tell me how or give a little advice or tip for me.

Thank you and I am really sorry if I am violating any rules of Stack Overflow without knowing it.

Comment: read this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional

Comment: In most cases having separate services for each repository is pointless. Service is supposed to represent business logic. In your case you will have a business logic method called `purchaseLottery` in your service which will coordinate with one or more repositories to update one or more tables. This is where the transactional boundaries should be.

Comment: `@Setu` Oh so does the `purchaseLottery` class uses both `UserRepository` and `CloverValidRepository`??? That was my concern. I thought I shouldn't do that. I make a method like `purchaseLottery(id : String)` in that class, then add `@Transactional` and adjust things that I want Spring Framework and JPA to do and it's all fine right??? Of course it won't be that easy but is that how I should plan before I write codes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple structure could be entity driven, in your case UserController/UserService/UserRepository/User.

Transactional boundaries belong to the service layer, you can use Spring annotations and use them on public methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just heard that the way you said is a good idea too. So after I refactor all these classes' packages, can I use two DAO interfaces (Repositories in the picture) in UserService or something? like as class variables? I mean sure I can do that but is that the right way? Actually this was what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Correct, inject Repository into Service so during your business logic (in a transactional context) you can access the DB.

Inject via Spring so you can mock the repository during unit testing

Comment: `@Beppe C`    Thank you. Thank you sir. May the force be with you.